# PowerApps: Filter by user no delegation

Tags: delegation, powerapps

Need some help with PowerApps - I am trying to filter the gallery where the Person column (ROMEmail) equals the logged in user.

This code is working, but the blue circle of death comes up - whilst in test at the moment, i dont have over 500 records, but will do within a month of trialling this

Any ideas on how to workaround this? Using a collection or variable perhaps? I haven't really used these yet so a detailed resolution would be greatly appreciated.

```
SortByColumns(Filter('Reviews', StartsWith(LocationName, TextSearchBox1.Text),ROMEmail.Email = User().Email), "Modified", If(SortDescending1, Descending, Ascending))
```

Answer (score 0):

A [collection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/create-update-collection) would be your best choice.

To add a collection in your app replace the code where you grab your data by something like this:

```
ClearCollect(localData,'Reviews')
```

This collects all the data in a locally collection. The [ClearCollect](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/functions/function-clear-collect-clearcollect) replaces all your data by the new ones.

After this you can sort and filter directly on your collection. For example in a gallery. Using your code it would look like this:

```
SortByColumns(Filter(localData, StartsWith(LocationName, TextSearchBox1.Text),ROMEmail.Email = User().Email), "Modified", If(SortDescending1, Descending, Ascending))
```